# Angular 5: Check type of a casted object

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I request from a REST-API with the `HttpClient` an array of `Tree` objects:

```
this.http.get<Tree[]>('url...');
```

The constructer of the tree objects wasn't called, but I need the Tree's class methods. So I build an overloaded constructor in the `Tree` class which accepts `obj: Tree` and set the class variables with the values from the given rest-api-object:

```
constructor(obj: Tree);
constructor(id: string, conf: Config);
constructor(idOrObj: string | Tree, conf?: Config){
 if(idOrObj instanceof Tree){
  this.id = idOrObj.id
  ...
 }
}
```

The `instanceof` check doesn't work, because the casted Tree object from the REST request isn't a "real" `Tree` object.

How can I check if the `idOrObj` parameter is a casted `Tree` object from the REST-API or just the id string?

Comment: Unfortunately typescript is not casting objects. Its just assuming that object is of given type for explicit purpose of static analysis - to help you write. Wherever you write a type you should thing of it as you are assuming values are of that type not that typescript will make them of that type in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Typing a request does not create a new instance of your class, it simply gives you IDE completion.

If you want to create a new instance of your class, you have several ways of doing so.

the easiest one is something like this

```
export class Tree {
  constructor(payload: any) {
    Object.assign(this, payload);
  }
}
```

Now to create a new instance simply do this

```
const t = new Tree(requestResponse);
```

Note that after that, `typeof t` will still return an object, but `t instanceof Tree` will return `true` and `t.constructor.name` will return `Tree`.

Comment: Sure I can overload constructors in Typescript. There exist several examples on StackOverflow!?

Comment: You can have overloaded signatures, you can't have overloaded implementations, aka there is a single function/constructor body and you have to figure out which signature was called

Comment: Sorry, that was my linter, not a typescript limitation. Doesn't change the rest of my answer though.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you for the precision !

Answer (score 1):

The simpler approach would be to test for the `string` parameter and asume it's a `Tree` otherwise:

```
class Tree {
    id: string
    constructor(obj: Tree);
    constructor(id: string, conf: Config);
    constructor(idOrObj: string | Tree, conf?: Config) {
        if (typeof idOrObj !== 'string' ) {
            Object.assign(this, idOrObj); // idOrObj  will be typed as Tree
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While writing this post, I thought about this solution. But maybe there is another way, for another situation. But thanks!